# Parse Regex from string format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am having my Regex in the string format like::

```
pattern="/[^abc]/g"
```

But I wanted to create `RegExp` object from this string pattern. Then i will do pattern match as ::

```
regex.test(key)
```

here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4QDZ/1/) link.

Comment: So do you have a question ?

Comment: He has regex format in string, but wanted to create "RegExp` object from that pattern string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `RegExp` class:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('[^abc]', 'g');
```

More information about RegExp: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Here's your JSFiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/W4QDZ/2/

Answer (score 0):

i think you need this :

```
var pattern= new RegExp("[^abc]","g");
console.log(pattern)
console.log(pattern.test("abca"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
  var pattern = "/[^abc]/g";
  var ary = pattern.split('/')
  var myRe = new RegExp(ary[1], ary[2]);
  myRe.test('fhe'); // true
  myRe.test('abc'); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RegExp` class to create a regular expression pattern.

If you define as string you cannot use that with `test` method.